# How to post current user's register form input into associated Database column - MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, user-input

How can I create/code a register form that will post a user's input into the associated SQL database column?

I have a register page that the user will input their username/password, click a link to confirm their email, and then once they have confirmed their email it asks them to log in. The problem is that I can't figure out how to 1) redirect the user to the page to fill out their information on another form based on a Customers Table and 2) how to post the input specifically to the user's associated column.

The register page is set to the Identity Table but the next form that I want to code is linked to the Customer Table

Here is my register page:

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.RegisterViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```